# Triggering Events upon properties changes and event subscription with Azure IoT Device Provisioning Service

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Is it possible to send out event or notification whenever the properties below are changed, and ideally the event can be routed to Azure Service Bus or similar?

```
{
  "tags": {
    "A": "Test",
    "B": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "desired": {
      "C": 1,
      "D": 2,
      "E": 3
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: have a look at the Azure IoT Hub feature for eventing and routing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#non-telemetry-events

Answer (score 2):

Your question belong to Azure IoT Hub Device Twins service.
As @Roman Kiss pointed out, you need to create a custom endpoint at *IoTHub->Message Routing->Custom endpoints* where you can choose Service Bus Queues:

[image -> Custom endpoints Service Bus Queues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIWux.png)

[image]

After that create a new Route at *IoTHub->Message Routing* by selecting the Device Twins Change Event as a Datasource and your new Service Bus endpoint:

[image -> Message Routing to Service Bus endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIwp0.png)

[image]

For reference:

- [Non-telemetry events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c#non-telemetry-events)
- [Custom endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-endpoints#custom-endpoints)
- [Backend operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#back-end-operations) (**Receive twin notification** section)